# Gnu Make auto-dependency generation

Tags: makefile, dependencies, auto-generate

Based on [this famous link](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) and adapted from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/maxtruxa/4b3929e118914ccef057f8a05c614b0f), and supposing that all of your source files are `.cpp`, you get easily a solution like this to have auto-dependence generation:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp)

DEPDIR := .d
DEPS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)

# Temporary .Td dependence file... ?
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

# Isn't it better a order-only prerequisite?
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(DEPS)) >/dev/null)

%.o: %.cpp # Removal of implicit rules... ? Twice?
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d  # Dependency on .d... ?
        g++ -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
        # Avoid some bugs?
        mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

# If the `%.d` dependency is removed, is this still necessary?
.PRECIOUS = $(DEPDIR)/%.d
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;

-include $(DEPS)
```

To don't make this question too long discussing deeply why I think that all of the lines commented in the snippet above are innecesary, I will ask it in a short form; is there any difference in behaviour if I just change this snippet to:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp)
DEPDIR := .d
DEPS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)

DEPFLAGS := -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

$(DEPDIR)/%:
        mkdir -p $@

%.o: %.cpp | $(DEPDIR)/$(dir %)
        g++ -o $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
        # touch $(DEPDIR)/$.d # ??

-include $(DEPS)
```

I have still two extra doubts; in the first link above, it says that

> it’s been reported that some versions of GCC may leave the object file
>   older than the dependency file, which causes unnecessary rebuilds.

However, in the `gist` (second link above), the `touch` command is removed, and since the dependence file is no longer prerequisite of any rule, is there any reason to keep including it? Does this "gcc bug" still apply in any form?

The second doubt is related to the directory creation, moved to an order-only rule; do I need to make the "order-only" `$(DEPDIR)/%` rule `.PRECIOUS`? I don't know if `make` will attempt to remove the directory if the `%.o` recipe fails, because I don't know the concrete features of order-only rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove the `%.d` prerequisite.  The reason this is needed [is explained](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#depdelete) in the page you linked.

I don't know what you mean by your comment *Removal of implicit rules... ? Twice?*.  The removal of the implicit rule is needed, to ensure that our new implicit rule is used, and we only remove it once.

The temporary file `.Td` is used in case someone uses ^C or similar to kill their make job right in the middle of creating this file.  By writing to a temporary file then only atomically replacing the real file once we know it's complete, we never have to worry about partial files which could cause the next invocation of make to generate an error or, worse, not recompile source files that should be recompiled.

Regarding the comment about object files older than the dependency file, first the gist you link to uses `clang` not GCC and perhaps Clang doesn't have this issue (or perhaps it does but people don't realize it).  Second that update to the blog post is relatively recent as people have reported this issue to me with GCC.  I've not seen it myself (I only use GCC) so maybe it's only an issue with some versions of GCC.

Regarding `.PRECIOUS`, `make` never (currently) recursively deletes directories so it won't delete any non-empty directory regardless of that setting.

Comment: About the "removal twice" comment, you have just below the same target again, (ok, with the extra .d dependency). Why isn't that redundant?

Comment: The first one deletes the built-in pattern because it doesn't have a recipe.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html  The second line is the start of creating a new pattern rule with a new recipe.  They're not the same thing at all.

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue with removing the dependency file, but it will recreate the `.o` as well, which is already updated, and will cause an unnecesary amount of work since recreating the dependency file is a pretty faster operation than compiling. Think of example of the removal of `main.d`. What would be a better solution for that case? I'm thinking on three options: order-only `%.d` dependency, `%.d` depending on `%.cpp` which bring us to square 1, or two different recipes, using `ifeq  according to whether `%.cpp` is in `$?` or isn't.

Comment: I don't see how an order-only `%.d` prerequisite will make any difference.  Also clearly you can't use `ifeq` because that's a make construct and can't be used inside a recipe.  You'd have to use a shell condition or else the `$(if ...)` make function.  IMO this is a micro-optimization for a rare corner case (people shouldn't be deleting `.d` files by hand) and it's not worth the added complexity it would require to avoid the compilation step.

Comment: you can use a make construct inside a recipe provide isn't tabulated: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html. But yes, maybe it's a worthless micro-optimization, although if, even by mistake or need, you delete the full `.d` directory, will cause the recreation of the whole project when the `.o` is just fine.

Comment: You can put a make conditional in a recipe, but it will be evaluated when the makefile is parsed, not when the recipe is expanded.  That means you can't check the contents of any of the automatic variables etc. because they are not available when the makefile is being parsed, only when the recipe is run later.  So you can't use these statements to check whether `$?` contains a specific value: it will always be the empty string.